# Replace Function not working with charcode

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to replace the value of `Selection.Text` but it's not working. The value is **^p^p[LAUGHTER]** and I want to replace the **carriage return(^p) with soft return(^l)** so I used `Replace Selection.Text, "^p", "^l"` but it doesn't work, it won't replace it.

Comment: Word? Something else? What's charcode?

Comment: yes, it's MS-Word. the charcode for the "^p" is `chr(13)` while the "^l" is `chr(11)` but I already tried using charcode and still doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recording a macro gets me this:

```
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "^l"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

You probably don't need `MatchSoundsLike`. :-)

Or following your original idea, try:

```
Selection.Text = Replace(Selection.Text,chr(13),chr(11))
```